# Needing guidance on making a simple daemon for unity notifications in a python app

Tags: unity, application-development, python, development, services

I am making an app using pygtk, glade, and quickly and want to make a daemon that runs in the background to provide unity notifications for alarms and events. I would like to find a way to not require root authentication after installing the *deb file. I have tried adding a script to the users crontab but it seems that would require the restart of crond. (which needs either root or a reboot) I was wondering if there was a project I should look at to see an example of a daemon in python or how I could go about this? Thank you in advance for any help and feel free to tell me I'm wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Daemons are usually run by root (although they sometimes change the user under they run).

For a normal notification you don't need to create a daemon, just create a normal program and let it run at the start of a session. This way it will run with user privileges, and you will run a separate instance for each user.

I have done this [program](https://code.launchpad.net/notificadorumbria), it's a bit more complex than what you need, as it uses different libraries to run in different systems but it is quite simple and maybe a good example.

Comment: I want to clarify, you are using `gobject.timeout_add(interval, callback, ...)` to check the alarm at a regular interval, aren't you? Does this function do checking in the main loop (*busy waiting* rather than idle)?

Comment: Yes, the gtk version is using gobject.timeout. I don't understand what you mean with checking in the main loop, but anyway it doesn't do any kind of busy waiting.